# How do I get a DXF file from Blender without splitting the faces into triangles?

Tags: autocad

I've got a flat model in Blender that I need to convert to DXF format for a laser cutter. However, when I export the file as a DXF, it automatically splits up every polygon face to a triangle.

I don't believe there is a way of deactivating it, as [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152991/how-to-export-to-dxf-file-without-the-geometry-having-a-triangular-mesh) asks the same thing, with Robert mentioning importing it via AutoCAD as a FBX, but the drawing doesn't appear at all in AutoCAD.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong StackExchange to post on - there doesn't seem to be one for AutoCAD

Comment: Do the fold lines export in a different colour or line type?

Comment: Since its a flat model, can you explode the polygons into lines prior to exporting?

Comment: @Transistor, no they don't (annoyingly)